# Python: Regular expression to change image filename

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string looks like this

String a is `ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2)`

String b is `\ewfsd\ss.jpg`

Expected outputs:

```
ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2, b_holder = \ewfsd\ss.jpg)
```

It adds the string b to the end of string a, that's it! But be careful of the ")"

"b_holder " is hard coded string, it's absolutly same in all cases, won't be changed.

Update: If regular expression is not a best choice here, please suggest a best way to do.

Comment: why do you think a regular expression is relevant here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you have? The code you've shown us is not Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is

```
a = "ACdA(a = %b, ccc= 2r2)"
b = "\ewfsd\ss.jpg"
print a[:-1] + ', b_holder = ' + b + ')'
```

what you had in mind?

Most days of the week, I personally prefer

```
print '%s, b_holder = %s)' % (a[:-1], b)
```

I recognize I'm likely in the minority in this particular regard.

There certainly are other implementations, some of them RE-based.  I favor the ones above, given what the original questioner has expressed.